# how to get automatic notification to android device(on notification bar) using phonegap 3.4?

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I have developed the apps in phonegap for android with cordova 3.4. my apps having dynamic list which is updated from server now what I want is suppose apps list will updated from server then android apps get automatically notification to their android device (means on notification bar) whatever apps is opened or not and I want to send the notification those user they installed the apps.
I have kept my apk on my private server from their user will download and install.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

for that you should basically use GCM with PushPlugin from Cordova.

A very detailed tutorial can be found here: http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/

Comment: I read above link but how to other users get the notification. is the my admin panel(my private server) link to the gcm?

Comment: I think you should also read the gcm tutorial for android: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html. Basically you need device_ids from your users you want to send notifications to